# How do I use DocumentDB bindings for queue triggers of json?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

In [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/functions-reference-node/) I can have a trigger of type "Queue" and then an input of type "documentdb". I can control which document is loaded and given to the function from Azure DocumentDB by stating `{queueTrigger}`.

This **works** if the message on my Queue is plain-text and the id of a document that exists in my configured document.

However, if my messages on the triggering Queue are JSON and contain the ID of the document as a property, how can I state something like:

`{queueTrigger.id}`

Attempting this gives an invalid template:

> 2016-04-22T06:39:03.044 Exception while executing function:
>   Functions.sagaReady_queueMessage_updatedSaga.
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Invalid template '{queueTrigger.id}'.
>   The parameter name 'queueTrigger.id' is invalid.

I tried a few variants, `{{queueTrigger.id}}`, `{queueTrigger}.id`, but I haven't been able to get the result I expect.

This is part of an [open source package](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/b1fb20b0edf0530d62127d6dd9f50cc9345ca7b6/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Bindings/Path/BindingTemplateParser.cs) which has a regular expression in it. I can see it supports {blah} and {{blah}} but without knowing the list of parameters I can't wire it up.

Can any point me at any other OSS code or shed some light on this?

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the property name as the input parameter, so if you  have an id in your JSON queue message, just use `{id}`.

In C#, you then need to create a POCO (a class) that exposes that property and use that class as the trigger argument type (e.g. `Run(MyType queueParam, ...)`)

Comment: If I use {id} as you suggest it warns me there is no value available:

Exception while executing function: Functions.sagaReady_queueMessage_updatedSaga. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: No value for named parameter 'id'.

Comment: Currently Node; but I'm in Azure Functions and polyglot enough to not mind developing it in either.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks! I have it working in C# with the inputDocument as {id} as you suggest. The same didn't work with node, but I'll use C# for this function.

Comment: I reproed this issue for Node.js and logged an issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/288). We'll fix that soon. Binding like this works in general across all the languages - we just have a bug in DocumentDb :)